# How to change chapter font style in the middle of the Table of the Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, memoir

What I do have, is grouped frontmatter entries (chapter-like) in ToC, and the rest of the chapters have larger vertical space.
What I want is to change the
font style of the grouped part to, say, normalfont or italics while keeping
the rest of the entries unchanged. How do I do this?

(In the future I might change entries of the chapters 1 to 3 to small caps or to something other format...)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setlength{\cftbeforesectionskip}{4pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{16pt}}}{}{}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}
\section{Section One Four}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}
\section{Section Two Three}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section Three One}
\section{Section Three Two}
\section{Section Three Three}
\section{Section Three Four}
\section{Section Three Five}

\end{document}
```

[image: A sample]

This is continuation to the question [Change vertical space of chapters temporarly in Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83348/change-vertical-space-of-chapters-temporarly-in-table-of-contents/83352#83352).
Package `etoolbox` is for the grouping the front matter entries.

Comment: Found a solution, kind of...  
Add `\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{}` to the preamble and
change the `\pretocmd...` to `\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{16pt}\bfseries}}{}{}`.  
Only problem is that if the grouped entries should be italics and the rest not, it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a new boolean switch (say, `specialtoc`). Set it (inside the `.toc` file) to true at the start of the document body and to false at the start of the main chapters. Redefine `\cftchapterfont` and `\cftchapterpagefont` (which are responsible to format ToC chapter entries) so that their meaning depends on the state of `specialtoc`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\cftbeforesectionskip}{4pt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{specialtoc}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{%
  \ifbool{specialtoc}{%
    \itshape
  }{%
    \bfseries
  }%
}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{%
  \ifbool{specialtoc}{%
    \itshape
  }{%
    \bfseries
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\booltrue{specialtoc}}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\boolfalse{specialtoc}}

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{16pt}}}{}{}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}
\section{Section One Four}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}
\section{Section Two Three}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section Three One}
\section{Section Three Two}
\section{Section Three Three}
\section{Section Three Four}
\section{Section Three Five}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I can see that you can use specialtoc multiple times (or add other boolean switches) to change the appearance of, say, bibliography or appendices.

As a side note, makes me wonder, why there is no options in memoir or a dedicated package to change the appearance of ToC to look like this - it does look better than the original!

Comment: I usually use the toc hooks to insert macro hooks into the toc file itself, and then in the preamble define what those hooks should do, I'm not a fan of changing `\chapter`. See `\cftinserthook` and `\cftinsertcode`, the later is for defining what a hook does. Adding things like locksteps solution would make `memoir` a lot more difficult to understand than it already is.

Comment: @daleif Because this question was continuation to other question, I used etoolbox. Your point makes this "nuisance" unnecessary, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Altough lockstep gave already very nice answer to the problem, I'll add minimal solution
based on daleif's comment on `\cftinserthook` and `\cftinsertcode`. This way the `etoolbox`-package is not needed at all.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{4pt}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\itshape}

\cftinsertcode{SPECIALTOC}{%
  \renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\bfseries}%
  \setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{16pt}%
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\cftinserthook{toc}{SPECIALTOC}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section Three One}
\section{Section Three Two}
\section{Section Three Three}

\end{document}
```

The output is similar to lokcstep's solution.

Comment: Beautiful. Can we get this using book.cls?