# Change format for frontmatter and backmatter items in memoir Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, memoir

In a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83482/211164), TKO successfully formatted `memoir` `\frontmatter` `\chapters` (in this case `Foreword` and `Abstract`) differently to `\mainmatter` items in a `\tableofcontents`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{4pt}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\itshape}

\cftinsertcode{SPECIALTOC}{%
  \renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\bfseries}%
  \setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{16pt}%
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\cftinserthook{toc}{SPECIALTOC}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section Three One}
\section{Section Three Two}
\section{Section Three Three}

\end{document}
```

But how can we apply this to other `\frontmatter` items (such as `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` or `\listoftables`) and to `\backmatter` items (such as `\printpagenotes`, `\printbibliography` or `\printindex`)?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{4pt}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\itshape}

\cftinsertcode{SPECIALTOC}{%
  \renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\bfseries}%
  \setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{16pt}%
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents % apply to this toc entry
\listoffigures % apply to this toc entry
\listoftables % apply to this toc entry
\chapter*{Foreword} % apply to this toc entry
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
\chapter*{Abstract} % apply to this toc entry
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\cftinserthook{toc}{SPECIALTOC}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section Three One}
\section{Section Three Two}
\section{Section Three Three}

\backmatter
\printpagenotes % apply to this toc entry
\printbibliography % apply to this toc entry
\printindex % apply to this toc entry

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are some issues with your sample doc. Under `\frontmatter` there is no need for the `\chapter*` + `\addcontentsline` combo, as that it de default for `\chapter` under `\frontmatter`. You just need more `\cftinserthook{toc}{NAME}`'s have a look in the `.toc` file then you'll have a better idea of what it is doing. Also, are you sure you want the toc in the toc? I'd just use `\tableofcontents*`

Comment: Very true, thanks @daleif. The combo slipped my mind when copying in TKO's original MWE. I have now incorporated your comments in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you just have to define another hook for `\backmatter`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{4pt}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\itshape}
\cftinsertcode{mainmattertoc}{%
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalsize\normalfont}%
    \setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{8pt}%
}
\cftinsertcode{backmattertoc}{%
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\itshape}%
    \setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{4pt}
}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\listoffigures % apply to this toc entry
\listoftables % apply to this toc entry
\chapter{Foreword} % apply to this toc entry
\chapter{Abstract} % apply to this toc entry

\cftinserthook{toc}{mainmattertoc}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter One}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\chapter{Chapter Three}

\cftinserthook{toc}{backmattertoc}

\backmatter
\printpagenotes % apply to this toc entry
\printbibliography % apply to this toc entry
\printindex % apply to this toc entry

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: I hardly ever use the `\backmatter` command, I see no need to disable numbering once again. But wanting to change the things you want to change there is quite common