# Bind vertical spacing change in ToC to \*matter commands

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, memoir

This is a spin-off question to [Change vertical space of chapters temporarly in Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83348/30821). Like in the question's answer, I managed to achieve custom vertical spacing of chapters before, during and after the main content.
In contrast to that question, I'm using memoir's `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` commands to separate these document parts semantically.

Now: **Is it possible to move the vertical spacing commands for chapters to the preamble somehow, e.g. by using the `\*matter` commands as a trigger?** I really would like to keep the custom formatting commands out of the document body as far as possible.

**MWE** with desired output, but with markup sprinkled throughout the document:

[image: TOC of a memoir document with custom spacing for chapters]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{3pt}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foreword}
\chapter{Abstract}

\mainmatter
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{6pt}}}{}{}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}
\section{Section One Four}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}
\section{Section Two Three}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section Three One}
\section{Section Three Two}
\section{Section Three Three}
\section{Section Three Four}
\section{Section Three Five}

\backmatter
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix One}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{-6pt}}}{}{}
\chapter{Appendix Two}
\chapter{Appendix Three}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i'm sure it should be possible.  my approach would be to add those definitions to the definitions of the `\*matter*` commands.  using a "patch" technique is what i'd look at, but i'm not familiar enough with `memoir` to suggest code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `etoolbox` for adding what you need.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{3pt}

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\ojdospacing}{}{}
\apptocmd{\mainmatter}{\let\ojdospacing\ojdospacingon}{}{}
\apptocmd{\backmatter}{\ojdospacing\let\ojdospacing\relax}{}{}
\newrobustcmd{\ojdospacingon}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{6pt}}%
}
\let\ojdospacing\relax % initialize

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foreword}
\chapter{Abstract}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}
\section{Section One Four}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}
\section{Section Two Three}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section Three One}
\section{Section Three Two}
\section{Section Three Three}
\section{Section Three Four}
\section{Section Three Five}

\backmatter
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix One}
\chapter{Appendix Two}
\chapter{Appendix Three}

\end{document}
```

When `\backmatter` is issued, `\ojdospacing` is executed one last time, then it is reverted to mean `\relax`.

[image]